# How do I extend the RequestLogger in the Cassandra Java driver to log the context of a REST API?

Tags: logging, cassandra, spring-data, spring-webflux, datastax-java-driver

The datastax-javar-driver provides a [way to log all queries](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/manual/core/logging/). But I need to intercept and log some context of a REST API.
My setup is Spring webflux using Spring data which internally uses datastax-java-driver. Is there a way for me to pass reactive contextView to RequestLogger or any other custom class that extends so that I can log all the custom details ?

I tried extending the class but I don't see any method I can override to pass custom context.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me that you would do this using the Cassandra Java driver's `RequestLogger`.

It's not clear to me what about some REST API you want to log but my suggestion is that you implement the logging within your application since what you want to achieve is likely not what the driver's request logger was designed for. Cheers!